# Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 550 Invalid recipient:

Tags: php

I'm creating a 'forgot password' page where the user enters their email address and the script finds the password associated to that email, and sends it to the stored email address.

I believe the problem has to do with my SMTP Mailserver. I am using WAMP which doesn't have one so I downloaded one that was free.

This is the php script I'm using:

```
    $id = checkEmail($email);
    $record = readMemberRecord($id);
    $password = @mysql_result($record,0,'cred');

    if($password){
        $email_subject = "Email Request";
        $email_body = "Your password is ".$password.".";
        $header = "NinjaMan";
        mail($email, $email_subject, $email_body,$header);
        $msg = "Your password has been sent to ".$email.".";
    }else{
        $msg = "Sorry, the email ".$email." wasn't found.";
    }
```

The $msg outputs properly so I know the code is passing the mail function.

Comment: If error message 'Invalid recipient' is not followed by an email address, I bet `$email` variable is empty.

Comment: var_dump your variables to see if they're what you expect them to be first. If they are then the problem is probably with your SMTP config in which case you may want to post over on serverfault.

Comment: its' not empty. the $msg variable in the second if statement is being outputted. It carries the $email variable and displays correctly. "$msg = "Your password has been sent to ".$email.".";" works.

Comment: Have you tried using telnet to troubleshoot this? It could also be a port issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try sending in a proper "From" in `$header`.

```
$emailFrom = "admin@yourdomain.com"; // match this to the domain you are sending email from
$email = "example@example.com";
$subject = "Email Request";
$headers = 'From:' . $emailFrom . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: " . $email . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-path: " . $email;
$message = "Your password is ".$password.".";
mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

See details of the [mail() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

If this doesn't work, try using [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/). You configure it in code, no need to edit php.ini.

I've used it in some projects (v 2.0.4, I see the latest is 5.1) and had no problems.

Comment: I made a mistake and edited the answer. The from address should be the one you are sending the email from.

Comment: OK I figured it out. 

Well, I found something that works. 

First I downloaded the phpMailer class and included it in script at the very top like this :require_once("PHPMailer_5.2.1/class.phpmailer.php");

Next I deleted the other SMTP I was using and downloaded a different one called PostCaster.

During set up it tried to make the SMTP thing the name of my computer. I just changed it after setup to 'localhost'.

Finally, I ran the script. The email went into postcaster, and I hit 'send' in post caster.

Comment: The email went into my spam folder immediately. Although because google expects an email sent by my own email address to be sent from google it labeled it a fraudulent email. 

So it works! I can set it to send emails automatically when they are recieved so I don't have to send them manually. It can also send them periodically. 

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try using Google's server to send mails, you can see how to do that [here](http://nekocm.blogspot.com/2011/02/sending-mails-from-localhost-with-xampp.html)

Comment: I would try that if xamp worked on my computer. I was getting an error that said something about an instance of something was already running and a port 88 not being accessable or something like that. So I switched to WAMP.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
//Email information
$to = "garggarima@gmail.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a test email message.";
$from = "support@sltechsoft.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;

$mail=mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
if($mail) {
    echo "Thanks for mail";
} else {
    echo "Mail not Sent";
}

//Email response
echo "Thank you for contacting us!";
```